# Fetching numbers of attending guests on a facebook event through the graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
    $accesstoken = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    $ret_obj = $facebook->api('366476673459158/attending', 'GET');
    print_r($ret_obj);
```

This is what I'm doing to try to just display the numbers of attending people of the event.
I just get an empty array.

PS : If I try to get the attending_count directly it just gives me an error.

$ret_obj = $facebook->api($agenda.'/invited', 'GET', array('summary' => 1));

Comment: Can’t reproduce that – pasting `/366476673459158/attending` into the Graph API Explorer gives me a list of users attending the event.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution :

```
 $ret_obj = $facebook->api($post.'/invited', 'GET', array('summary' => 1));
 $attending_count = $ret_obj['summary']['attending_count'];
```

but it also returns the entire list of invited when I only need the summary. No work around seems to exist.